# phpExcel xls to csv conversion is changing the date to raw

Tags: php, phpexcel

my function to convert xls file to csv using phpExcel is changing the value in the date field to raw. How do I avoid this from happening?

The function is as below

```
function convertXLStoCSV($infile,$outfile)
{
    $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);    

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->save($outfile);
}
```

The date in the xls file is of the format: 16.01.2017  00:00:00
The output csv file has the date in the format: 42751.0104166667

I have tried to change in file /Classes/PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php

```
        self::$_builtInFormats[22] = 'm/d/yy h:mm'; 
        changed to 
        self::$_builtInFormats[22] = 'mm.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss';
```

But this is not doing the magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

which is explicitly telling PHPExcel to read the cell data as raw data, without any of the styling information (such as number format masking).

Simply comment out that line

Comment: thanks, commenting the line does not help. the output is still the same

Comment: That's very odd, because the CSV Writer is explicitly set to precalculate all formulae, and to format the output using the defined number format mask for each cell; so it certainly shouldn't be outputting a raw datetimestamp value, and I've just double-checked the code to confirm that... so I can't understand how you can be getting a raw value

Comment: you are right. If I save the excel sheet before converting it works. however when i save it changes the decimal places of all the other fields. Here is my untouched file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0rMch-nfpzmdlphcmRPWXdGblE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: commenting $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   is also removing the decimal places of all other fields

Comment: The number of decimals displayed is also dependent on the format mask applied to the cell, without the format mask (not loaded when setReadDataOnly is true), then PHP will use the datatype integer for values loaded as integers, and which should then be displayed as integers; but float values loaded from the file should render based on php.ini's precision setting